# BlazorDateRangePicker SingleDatePicker buttons not visible

Tags: blazor

I'm using BlazorDateRangePicker https://github.com/jdtcn/BlazorDateRangePicker
I have below code where I've SingleDatePicker=true. Due to this the buttons are not visible.

```
<DateRangePicker SingleDatePicker="true" 
  @bind-StartDate="StartDate" 
  @bind-EndDate="EndDate" 
  Context="contekst"
  ApplyButtonClasses="single-picker-buttons">
  <ButtonsTemplate>
      <button class="cancelBtn btn btn-sm btn-default" @onclick="@contekst.ClickCancel" type="button">
          Cancel
      </button>
      <button class="cancelBtn btn btn-sm btn-default" @onclick="@(e => ResetClick(e, contekst))" type="button">
          Reset
      </button>
      <button class="applyBtn btn btn-sm btn-primary" @onclick="@contekst.ClickApply" disabled="@(contekst.TStartDate == null || contekst.TEndDate == null)" type="button">
          Apply
      </button>
  </ButtonsTemplate>
```

```
@code {
   DateTimeOffset? StartDate { get; set; }
   DateTimeOffset? EndDate { get; set; }

   void ResetClick(MouseEventArgs e, DateRangePicker picker)
   {
      StartDate = null;
      EndDate = null;
      // Close the picker
      picker.Close();
      // Fire OnRangeSelectEvent
      picker.OnRangeSelect.InvokeAsync(new DateRange());
   }
}
```

Above code is from the documentation at: https://github.com/jdtcn/BlazorDateRangePicker

Comment: [Polite] Raise an issue on the Github site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons get hidden when the component is in such a mode where it can auto apply the provided value. You can control this thrugh a parameter called `AutoApply`. The odd thing is that its defualt value is different based on whether the component is in single or multi mode, which might be a bit confusing.

To solve your issue and show the buttons, you can do one of the following:

1. explicitly set the `AutoApply="false"`
2. override the `display` styling applied to their `div` wrapper.

Both workarounds are shown here: https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/wHkbnaYW46S27TQd50